# Firebase functions: getting document data inside a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

im making a type of chat app. Im trying to write a firestore function that listens to a specific document that, when updated, will trigger the function to send a push notification to a specific user. However, im receiving an error. So far, i have:

```
export const messageListener = functions.firestore
    .document("stingrayMessageListener/stingrayMessageListener")
    .onWrite(async (change) => {
      const beforeData = change?.before?.data();
      const afterData = change?.before?.data();
      if (beforeData?.receiverId!=afterData?.receiverId) {
        const docRef = admin.firestore().doc("users/${afterData?.receiverId}");
        const docSnap = await docRef.get();
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: "New message!",
            body: "${afterData?.senderName} has sent you a message!",
          },
          data: {
            body: "message",
          },
        };
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(docSnap.data()?.token, payload);
      }
    });
```

This function is spitting out the following error:

> Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array

Im pretty sure this is implying that docSnap() is returning as null, because token is a field on all user documents. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why don't you add some lines of code to print the values that you're trying to use and see if they are what you expect.  The snapshot itself will never be null, so there is something else we can't see.  I'll point out that we can't see the contents of the trigger document before or after the update, and we can't see the contents of the document you're getting within the trigger.

Comment: Agreed with Doug here. I'd probably `console.log(docSnap.data())` to see what you're getting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in your document paths as you answered, both `beforeData` and `afterData` are assigned to `change?.before?.data()`, meaning your function won't send notifications to any device:

```ts
const beforeData = change?.before?.data();
const afterData = change?.before?.data();
if (beforeData?.receiverId != afterData?.receiverId) {
    //above condition won't be true
...
```

You'd only need to use the [after](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions.change-1) property which holds the changed document.

```ts
const afterData = change?.after?.data();
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out it was a very simple solution. In Typescript, you can dont use "" to use a variable in a string. You use ``.